MSVC Linker: /NODEFAULTLIB and /DEFAULTLIB option
I noticed that the MSVC linker from Microsoft has among many other options these two options: /NODEFAULTLIB and /DEFAULTLIB.
The documentation says:

By default, /NODEFAULTLIB removes all default libraries from the list
of libraries it searches when resolving external references.
[...]
The
linker resolves references to external definitions by searching first
in libraries that you explicitly specify, then in default libraries
specified by the /DEFAULTLIB option, and then in default libraries
named in .obj files.

I do not really understand why someone would first specify default libraries with /DEFAULTLIB and then undo this option with the /NODEFAULTLIB option? My assumption is that the linker adds default libraries other than the ones specified with the /DEFAULTLIB option, like the CRT library. But I couldn't find a list of these "hard" default libraries in the documentation that the linker includes. Its kind of magic what ends up in the resulting binary.
I hope someone can clarify my probably wrong understanding of these two options and point me to the right piece of documentation.
